# Marginal density from joint distribution of 3 random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose random variables X, Y, Z have joint probability density function given as 
\begin{equation}
  f_{XYZ}(x,y,z) = \frac{2x}{(A_2-A_1)(R_2^{2} - R_1^{2})y^{2}z} e^{-z^{2}/2}
\end{equation}
where A1,A2,R1,R2 are constant.
How do I find the marginal probability density function of X, if the support is
    \begin{cases}\ R_1yz\leq x \leq  R_2yz \\ A_1 \leq y \leq A_2  \\ 0 \leq z < \infty & \end{cases}
I know that I need to integrate with respect to Y (the will be two regions, I guess) and Z to find marginal P.D.F. of X. But I don't know what the boundary of the integrals should be, especially I cant understand how to deal with the range of Z ($ \infty $ is causing the main problem). What will be the final range of PDF of X. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the joint density? What are $A_1$ and $A_2$? By $\inf$ do you mean $\infty$?

Comment: @ Math 1000, I have edited the question. Please have a look.